# One SQL query using a select result in next sub queries in same request

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a possibility to (re)use one SQL select result to get the value of different sub selects inside that same query

First I should get the $ValueToUse with a select like:

```
SELECT `cb_campaignid` as ValueToUse FROM `#__team_groups` WHERE `id` = '$Value'
```

and with that "ValueToUse" result I want to do the next selects, if possible, in the same SQL-query statement.

```
SELECT coalesce (nullif (SUM(Amount), ''), '0') as general_amount, 
(SELECT SUM(c.cb_stand) FROM #__employees c, #__team_users u where c.user_id=u.user_id and u.group=(select id from #__team_groups where cb_campaignid='$ValueToUse')) as teamleden_tussenstand, 
(select title from #__customer_campaigns where id='$ValueToUse') as title, 
(select id from #__team_groups where cb_campaignid='$ValueToUse') as groupID, 
(select goal from #__customer_campaigns where id='$ValueToUse') as goal
 FROM #__customer_payments WHERE published = 1 and campaign_id = '$ValueToUse'
```

What will be the best way to get these results?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

How about using your first result as variable?

```
SELECT @ValueToUse:=
(SELECT `cb_campaignid` as ValueToUse FROM `#__team_groups` WHERE `id` = '$Value');

SELECT coalesce (nullif (SUM(Amount), ''), '0') as general_amount, 
(SELECT SUM(c.cb_stand) FROM #__employees c, #__team_users u where c.user_id=u.user_id and u.group=(select id from #__team_groups where cb_campaignid=@ValueToUse)) as teamleden_tussenstand, 
(select title from #__customer_campaigns where id=@ValueToUse) as title, 
(select id from #__team_groups where cb_campaignid=@ValueToUse) as groupID, 
(select goal from #__customer_campaigns where id=@ValueToUse) as goal
 FROM #__customer_payments WHERE published = 1 and campaign_id = @ValueToUse;
```